# NodeJS and Python communication via ChildProcess.spawn()

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a child process in NODEJS and i want to send data to a python file.

The Python File on the other hand reads this input from NODEJS, manipulates the data and sends it back to NodeJS.

How do i read the input on python side?

**NodeJS**

```
        const scriptExecution = spawn(pythonExecutable, ['-u', myPythonScript]);

    // SEND DATA
    scriptExecution.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(json_data));

    // RECEIVE DATA
    scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
```

So receiving data from Python is possible through the *print()* method. But how do i read the incoming Messages from NodeJS in python? My approach is not working:

**Python File**

```
def main():
    data = sys.argv
    print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

what is the right way to read child process data with **ChildProcess.stdin.write()** ?